# How to make scrollable box start from the right side contents instead of the left

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Right now, I have a scrollable box, but the box starts displaying the leftmost contents first and then we can scroll to see the contents to the right. Is there a way to start displaying the rightmost contents first and then start scrolling to the left after?

Comment: not completely sure if it works but flip the layout direction before the scrollable box, then flip it again for the contents. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi @abcdefasf, did any of the answers solve your question? If so, please accept it using a checkmark under the votes counter. Otherwise, let us know if you have any problems with them.

Answer (score 0):

You could animate to the last offset in the box, and use a variable to keep track of whether you already have done that. Use a Boolean value using `remember` so that you don't animate to end on every recomposition

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `LazyRow`, which has `reverseLayout` parameter.

```
val list = (0..100).toList()
LazyRow(
    reverseLayout = true,
) {
    items(list.reversed()) { // reverse items back
        Text(
            it.toString(),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
        )
    }
}
```